How I change my code to give the user 3 attempts for the username and password
I have attached a file which sums up what i need to add to my code, please someone help me
enter image description here
userNames = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5"]
print("Welcome to AQA User Registration")
for x in range(3):
  userName = input("New username: ")
  if userName in userNames:
    print("The username is already used")
  else:
    break
for x in range(3):
  userPassword = input("Password (12 characters or more): ")
  if len(userPassword) < 12:
    print("The password is not long enough")
  else:
    break
print("Your username is " + userName)
print("Your password is " + userPassword)            

I tried to use "for x in range(2)" to repeat it 3 times but even if the user enters a different username, it still ends the program. It is not in this code because it is very messy. I spent 1 hour trying to figure it out and I couldn't do so I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Use a for loop in conjunction with break

I did the exact same thing but it didnt work

Please edit your question to show the code where you used the for loop

alright give me 8 mins or less

I have done edited it

You should learn to use a debugger which allows you to step through the code and check the execution so you can resolve such issues yourself. As a start see python tutor

You need two loops - one each for the username and password inputs. If a valid username is not entered then you should not proceed to asking for a password.
You'll find the for/else contruct useful.
Here's a trivial way to do this:
import sys

userNames = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5"]

print("Welcome to AQA User Registration")

for _ in range(3):
    u = input("New username: ")
    if u.lower() in map(str.lower, userNames):
        print(u, "is already in use")
    else:
        # append username to list of known users
        userNames.append(u)
        break
else:
    print("Too many attempts")
    # terminate the program
    sys.exit()


for _ in range(3):
    p = input("Password (12 characters or more): ")
    if len(p) >= 12:
        # get the last username from the list of known users
        u = userName[-1]
        print("Your username is", u)
        print("Your password is", p)
        break
    else:
        print("The password is not long enough")
else:
    print("Too many attempts")

A better approach is to write discrete functions for the acquisition of the username and the password. This simplifies the code considerably and avoids the use of sys.exit():
userNames = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5"]

print("Welcome to AQA User Registration")

def getUserName():
    for _ in range(3):
        u = input("New username: ")
        if not u.lower() in map(str.lower, userNames):
            return u
        print(f"{u} is already in use")

def getPassword():
    for _ in range(3):
        p = input("Password (12 characters or more): ")
        if len(p) >= 12:
            return p
        print("The password is not long enough")

if (u := getUserName()) is not None and (p := getPassword()) is not None:
    print(f"Your username is {u}")
    print(f"Your password is {p}")
else:
    print("Too many attempts")


Thanks so much but can you please add comments on some of the parts? Like the part where it says userNames[-1] because I do not understand why it is used.

Thanks so much, I really appreciate it

You can count the number of attempts
userNames = ["User1", "User2", "User3", "User4", "User5"]
print("Welcome to AQA User Registration")
user_tries,pass_tries = 3,3
userName = input("New username: ")
if userName in userNames:
  print("The username is already used")
else:
    while user_tries > 0:
       userName = input("New username: ")
       if userName.lower() in [user.lower() for user in userNames]:
          print("The username is already used")
          break
        else:
           user_tries -= 1

userPassword = input("Password (12 characters or more): ")
if len(userPassword) >= 12:
   print("Your username is " + userName)
   print("Your password is " + userPassword)
else:
   while pass_tries > 0:
      userPassword = input("Password (12 characters or more): ")
      if len(userPassword) >= 12:
         print("Your username is " + userName)
         print("Your password is " + userPassword)
         break
      else:
         pass_tries -= 1   


Why do you ask for a password when there was no valid username input?

This code doesnt work
